How to Change cell color using conditional formatting with specific range of values
I have spreadsheet file and i was trying to change the color of the cells with condition specific range, but i think i have issue with my formula.
Conditional Formatting Formula
Column in the spreadsheet
in the second image i was trying to use conditional formatting for rule 1: in between values in the range 0.50-0.96 but the image show that the column were 1.32,1.2,etc values are also the cells with color.

Change the first open field to just .5 and the second one to just .96, no other text

I tried to change values without text but it doesn't work.

While Is Between rule must work, you can also try custom rule as
=($A1>=0.5)*($A1<0.96)



If I understood correctly, you're looking to change the color of the numbers from 0.50 - 0.96.  If that is the case then you just need to change the numbers in the Format rules as follows:


I also try to do this, but it doesn't change the cell color.

Any chance those cells formatted as Plain text instead of Number or Automatic?
